# How can I import and re-export a text file without changing the spacing or columns?

Tags: r, read.table

I have a file (prf003.tre) generated from some old proprietary software, that I am trying to edit in R. 
It is structured as such:

```html
0001  116.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0           
0001  216.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0           
0001  316.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0           
0001  416.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0           
0001  516.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0           
0001  616.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0           
0001  716.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0
```

The goal is to be able to import the file, modify the values in column 2 to read

> prf003[, 2]<- seq.int(nrow(prf003))

and then re-export the file.

(Between each cell are about 10-20 spaces depending on what column. Unfortunately copying this into stackoverflow does not make it appear this way, so I pasted it as code, hope that is okay, sorry I am newb. I need to preserve the integrity of the spacing.)

I tried to import into R, trying both read.table and readLines. read.table does not preserve the spacing, however I am unable to modify column 2 using readLines, given that it reads it as one column. Any suggestions? Perhaps there is a setting in read.table that I am not aware of, but searching has brought up nothing.

edit: read.Table also drops the 0's at my first column, any tips on how to preserve the "0001" would be helpful.

Comment: What does the spacing look like in your source file? Are you trying to preserve an exact number of spaces between columns?

Comment: Also, using `read.table(data, colClasses = "character")` will prevent the leading zeros from being dropped.

Comment: @Mako212 The spacing is as shown in the data table I've pasted-> there are 2 spaces between col 1 and col 2, 1 space between 2 and 3, and 3 and 4, 5 spaces between col 4 and 5, 13 spaces between col 5 and 6, and 8 spaces between col 6 and 7.
"Are you trying to preserve an exact number of spaces between columns?"
Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use R functions on a column, we need to convert to data frame first. This means we're going to need to reconstruct the source file spacing at the end.

First, we'll read with `colClasses = 'character'` to preserve leading zeros:

```
prf003 <- read.table(data, colClasses = "character")

prf003[, 2] <- seq.int(nrow(prf003))
```

Now, we'll define a vector for the column spacing, (note, we need an empty element at the end since there are no spaces after the last column):

```
spacing <-  c("  ", " ","   ","     ", "             ", "        ","")
```

And use `mapply` with `paste0` to add those spaces to the end of each column (this applies `paste0(prf003[ ,1], spacing[[1]])`, `paste0(prf003[ ,2], spacing[[2]])`, etc.:

```
formatted_prf <- mapply(paste0, prf003, spacing)
```

Then we can write back to your original file format using `write.table`

```
write.table(formatted_prf, "new_prf.tre", sep = "", quote = FALSE, 
  col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Noting that both `sep` must be empty, and `quote = FALSE` for this not to screw up our spacing.

This is the output of `write.table`:

```
0001  1 1BF   19.2     0.0             5500        0
0001  2 1BF   19.2     0.0             5500        0
0001  3 1BF   19.2     0.0             5500        0
0001  4 1BF   19.2     0.0             5500        0
0001  5 1BF   19.2     0.0             5500        0
0001  6 1BF   19.2     0.0             5500        0
0001  7 1BF   19.2     0.0             5500        0
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have the character vector `L` read in using `readLines` as shown in the Note at the end.  Then assuming you want the replacement of column 2 to also have 2 digits after the decimal:

```
substr(L, 7, 12) <- sprintf("%6.2f", seq_along(L))
writeLines(L, stdout()) # replace stdout() with "myfile.dat", say
```

giving:

```
0001    1.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0
0001    2.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0
0001    3.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0
0001    4.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0
0001    5.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0
0001    6.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0
0001    7.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "0001  116.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0           
0001  216.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0           
0001  316.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0           
0001  416.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0           
0001  516.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0           
0001  616.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0           
0001  716.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0"
L <- trimws(readLines(textConnection(Lines)))
```

Comment: Thank you. This almost works, except for some bizarre reason at line 10 the output 
 starts to add a new column before column 2

`"0001 1 10.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0"`
Note the value 1 in column 2. 
It does this for all subsquent lines.

Comment: Are ;you saying that the input is not in the form shown in the question?  If that is the case then clearly the code must be changed appropriately.

Comment: The input is the same form as shown in the question, however contains many more lines than was necessary for an example. The only difference is line 10 onwards has 4 digits instead of 3 at column 2, which is probably what causes the error
`0001 1016.00 1BF 19.2     0.0             5500        0`

Comment: If the digits go from columns 6 to 12 instead of 7 to 12 then replace 7 with 6 in substr and use 7 instead of 6 in sprintf since we need to fill out one more character position.